# Python Speech Recognition Microphone does not recognize speech

Tags: python, speech-recognition, microphone, pyaudio, portaudio

I want to use speech recognition to recognize speech from the microphone (built in on Mac Book Pro / air pods).

So I followed the instructions and installed port audio.

```
brew info portaudio
```

returns:
`portaudio: stable 19.7.0 (bottled), HEAD`

And in my project (pipenv environment), I installed PyAudio and SpeechRecognition.
My pipenv graph looks like this:

```
cffi==1.14.5
- pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.20]
pocketsphinx==0.1.15
PyAudio==0.2.11
SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
```

Recognizing speech from audio files works, but whenever I use the Microphone, it doesn't. For example, when I enter this command into the console for testing:

```
python3 -m speech_recognition
```

This gets printed:

```
A moment of silence, please...
Set minimum energy threshold to 45.131829621150224
Say something!
```

But it does not react to my voice.

Or when I run this code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

    # recognize speech using Sphinx
    try:
        print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

There is no error message, but nothing happens afterwards even if I say something.

When I run

```
print(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names())
```

I get back

```
['AirPods of MyName', 'AirPods of MyName', 'Built-in Microphone', 'Built-in Output']
```

So the microphones should be recognized.

Comment: cam you share the code

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I added the code

Comment: please try the code without using try-excpet and see if it's throwing any error

Comment: @Devakumarkp Still no error

Comment: could fix the indentation of print("Say something!") and try again

Comment: @Devakumarkp Still does not work. But I don't think that this is a problem concerning the code, but something with the dependencies, because when I execute this command for testing: "python3 -m speech_recognition" it still doesn't work

Comment: put r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) just below with statement and give indentation to try and except block

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I updated the code in the question. But it still does not work.

Comment: try with r.recognize_google() instead of sphinx

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Doesn't work. when using an audio file, both google and sphinx work, but with the microphone, it doesn't.

Comment: try to print this sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Added the output to the question ( at the bottom)

Comment: give different device_index in sr.Microphone()

Comment: not working i guess??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh No :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231491/discussion-between-bhavya-parikh-and-patrick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exact problem. I don't know if this has been resolved for you.

The problem for me was with using an integrated terminal in VS Code...as noted here [Python speech recognition is stuck (Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756231/python-speech-recognition-is-stuck-mac)

I tried the external terminal (iTerm) and everything works well. My terminal actually had to get permission to access my microphone. It seems the integrated terminal in VS Code isn't receiving permission to use it...will have to figure that one out later.

PS - After a quick search the one answer to this is posted here [Mac OS Mojave microphone permission for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277449/mac-os-mojave-microphone-permission-for-visual-studio-code)
It's still a little janky but...works.

Comment: I tried it again today and this time VS Code asked for permission to use the mic and it worked. Yes, seems to have been a problem with VS Code